# Python: How to execute statement and break in same line?

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop, inline, break

I am currently working on a coding competition that requires the least amount of characters used to accomplish a task. I have many if statements in it which are in a while loop, and each one requires a break statement. Currently, my code is:

```py
while <something>:
   if <something> is <something>:
      <do this>
      break
```

to shorten this I can do:

```py
while <something>:
   if <something> is <something>:<do this>
```

But according to my knowledge, I can't break after this. Is there any way to break and execute a statement in the same line?

Comment: execute and break in the same line? like ` return ( expression ) `?

Comment: whats the language?

Comment: I am not even using a function @zubergu

Comment: @Lux check edit

Comment: use a semicolon `;` to put multiple statements on the same line

Comment: or use `elif`..?

Comment: semicolon, but why? It's easier to read if the commands are on separate lines, per convention.

Comment: if all `if` inside `while`  need `break` then it will run only one loop and you don't need `while` and `break`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All expressions are statements, but not all statements are expressions.

`if` and `else` *expressions* are ternary operators. The expressions are evaluated. `break` and `continue` are statements. A statement isn't evaluated, it's executed. Statements cannot be used as an expression, we can use an expression in shorthand code but not a statement.

Statements must be separated by newlines or semicolons. So you can write

```html
while <something>:
   if <something> is <something>:<do this> ; break
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi you chan make a else statment at the last with continue like this

```
while ...:
    if ... is ...: (your work here)
    elif ... is ...: (your work here)
    ...
    . 
    .
    else:
        continue
    break
```

If nothing is satisfied else will do the loop again due to continue
and is something is satisfied it will break